# Pandas add column with formula

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, formula

I want to add a column beside qty naming "additional qty".
This will have a formula as current row - previous row of Qty.
e.g. in the second row the value should be 11(44-33); in the third row value should be 9(53-44) and so on for entire col.

```
qty_data= pd.read_csv('04-08-20.txt', sep=';')
qty_data.columns = ('item','Qty')
print(qty_data)

Output:
      item  Qty 
0       A   33  
1       B   44  
2       C   53  
3       D   89  
4       D   129
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`df.shift()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html):

```
In [2580]: df['additional qty'] = df.Qty - df.Qty.shift()

In [2581]: df
Out[2581]: 
  item  Qty  additional qty
0    A   33             NaN
1    B   44            11.0
2    C   53             9.0
3    D   89            36.0
4    D  129            40.0
```